# Parallelized Sobel algorithm using OpenMP

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, opencv, openmp

I implemented the Sobel algorithm sequentially, and got decent performance (1.49 s) but wanted to improve it. I parallelized it with OpenMP and got a ~3x speedup (0.523 s). I'd like to do better, but I'm not sure how.

```
// -------  C/C++ includes ------
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

// ------ OpenCV includes ------
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// dimension of kernel
int x[3][3];
int y[3][3];

/*----- OpenMP -----*/
int num_of_threads, i ,j;
double start, end;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat initialImage = imread(argv[1], 0); // imread gray-scale image
    Mat finalImage = Mat::zeros(initialImage.size(), initialImage.type());

    if (finalImage.type() == initialImage.type() )
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }

    if(argc != 2 || !initialImage.data)
    {
        cout << "No image data or Usage: ./sobel imagePath" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
      cout << "Image OK!" << endl; 

    //x direction
    x[0][0] = -1;  x[0][1] = 0;  x[0][2] = 1;
    x[1][0] = -2;  x[1][1] = 0;  x[1][2] = 2;
    x[2][0] = -1;  x[2][1] = 0;  x[2][2] = 1;

    //y direction
    y[0][0] = -1;  y[0][1] = -2;  y[0][2] = -1;
    y[1][0] =  0;  y[1][1] =  0;  y[1][2] =  0;
    y[2][0] =  1;  y[2][1] =  2;  y[2][2] =  1;

    num_of_threads = 8;//omp_get_num_procs();
    omp_set_num_threads(num_of_threads);

    start = omp_get_wtime();
    for(j = 0; j < initialImage.rows - 2; j++ ){
      #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
      for(i = 0; i < initialImage.cols -2; i++ ){
        // applay karnel in x direction
        int xValOfPixel = 
         (x[0][0] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j, i    )) + (x[0][1] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i    )) + (x[0][2] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i    )) +
         (x[1][0] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j, i + 1)) + (x[1][1] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i + 1)) + (x[1][2] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 1)) +
         (x[2][0] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j, i + 2)) + (x[2][1] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i + 2)) + (x[2][2] * (int)initialImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 2));

        // apply karnel in y direction
        int yValOfPixel =
         (y[0][0] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j, i    )) + (y[0][1] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i    )) + (y[0][2] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i    )) +
         (y[1][0] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j, i + 1)) + (y[1][1] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i + 1)) + (y[1][2] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 1)) +
         (y[2][0] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j, i + 2)) + (y[2][1] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 1, i + 2)) + (y[2][2] * (int)finalImage.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 2));


         int sum = abs(xValOfPixel) + abs(yValOfPixel);
         if(sum > 255)
          sum = 255;

        finalImage.at<uchar>(j, i) = (uchar)sum;
      }
    }
    end = omp_get_wtime();

    cout << "Time: " << end - start << endl;

    // display the images
    namedWindow("Initial Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Final Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Initial Image",initialImage);
    imshow("Final Image",finalImage);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've updated your title to describe what the code actually does, and clarified the body of your question.

Comment: How many cores did you use for your tests?  A 3x speedup is great if you use 4 cores, not so great if you have 12.  Are we to infer 8, given the call to `omp_set_num_threads()`?

Comment: I tested with 2, 4 and 8. I have 8 cores, sorry I upload the code without number removed. By default I used function omp_get_num_procs();

Comment: @Dannnno thank you for edit! I want to improve my code, if it's possible to have more better results or explain how to use correctly the OpenMP library. For example how to use OpenMP for better result. I'm a beginner in OpenMP :D Thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Avoid `using namespace`

Especially for large namespaces such as `std`, bringing so many identifiers into scope is dangerous.  Prefer to import just the identifiers you need, and/or qualify at use; as it is, I get a compilation failure:

```
195834.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
195834.cpp:81:5: error: reference to ‘end’ is ambiguous
     end = omp_get_wtime();
     ^~~
```

### Don't include `<stdio.h>` and `<time.h>`.

When writing new code, prefer `<cstdio>` and `<ctime>`, which brings the names into the `std` namespace.  Even better, omit these includes entirely, as we don't need them.

And do include `<cmath>`, so we have a declaration for `std::abs()`.

### Don't put everything in `main()`

There's three parts to this program.  It's easier to follow if we split the input and output from the processing.

### Avoid global variables

Part of the problem with `end` above is that it's declared global when it has no right to be.  Keep the scope of your variables as small as reasonably possible (and give them more meaningful names!).  Similarly, the kernels can be declared within the function:

```
static const int x[3][3] = { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -2, 0, 2 }, { -1, 0, 1 }};
static const int y[3][3] = { { -1, -2, -1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 2, 1 }};
```

### Use the correct output streams

Use `std::cerr` for reporting errors, and `std::clog` for other diagnostics.

### Check `argv[1]` is valid *before* using it.

We have

```
Mat initialImage = imread(argv[1], 0); // DANGER

// ...

if(argc != 2 || !initialImage.data)
```

We hit undefined behaviour if we access `argv[1]` before discovering that `argc < 2`.

### Use the correct image for the y-gradient

We should be using `initialImage`, not `finalImage` to compute `yValOfPixel`, otherwise we'll always get zero.

### Use a bigger work unit

You'll get better parallelisation if you make the *outer* loop a parallel-for, rather than the inner loop.  Since each row is the same length, you're better off dividing the work into bigger chunks

### Hard-code the Sobel coefficients

Since this isn't a general kernel convolution, we can help the compiler by using the constants in-place.  This allows the multiplication by small constants to be replaced by addition or subtraction (or omitted entirely for the six 0s).

### Use standard functions to limit values

Instead of the ad-hoc test for `sum` exceeding 255 (and no test for below zero), we can use `std::clamp()` (from `<algorithm>`).

---

## Modified code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


cv::Mat sobel_transform(const cv::Mat& input)
{
    cv::Mat finalImage = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), input.type());

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < input.rows-2;  ++j) {
        for (int i = 0;  i < input.cols-2;  ++i) {
            // applay karnel in x direction
            int xValOfPixel =
                -     (int)input.at<uchar>(j, i    ) +     (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 2, i    )
                - 2 * (int)input.at<uchar>(j, i + 1) + 2 * (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 1)
                -     (int)input.at<uchar>(j, i + 2) +     (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 2);

            // apply karnel in y direction
            int yValOfPixel =
                - (int)input.at<uchar>(j, i    ) - 2 * (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 1, i    ) - (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 2, i    )
                + (int)input.at<uchar>(j, i + 2) + 2 * (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 1, i + 2) + (int)input.at<uchar>(j + 2, i + 2);


            int sum = std::clamp(std::abs(xValOfPixel) + std::abs(yValOfPixel), 0, 255);

            finalImage.at<uchar>(j, i) = (uchar)sum;
        }
    }

    return finalImage;
}


#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./sobel imagePath" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const cv::Mat initialImage = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (!initialImage.data) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read image" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    const cv::Mat finalImage = sobel_transform(initialImage);
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();

    std::clog << "Time: " << end_time - start_time << std::endl;

    // display the images
    cv::namedWindow("Initial Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::namedWindow("Final Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Initial Image", initialImage);
    cv::imshow("Final Image", finalImage);

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't want an answer that simply said "use `cv::Sobel` instead"...